# Postgresql debugger issue

Tags: debugging, postgresql

I can't  debug in pgAdmin, I get always an error:

```
pldbg_get_target_info(unknown, unknown) function don't exist.
```

I've executed manually this function without problems.

The environment is **win7 64**, but **32b** installation. PG versions are: **pgAdmin 1.16.1** and **Postgresql 9.2.4**.

Comment: Sounds like the PL/PgSQL debugger extension isn't installed in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks @craig-ringer, I've this in my postgresql.conf: shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll' and this is the right path for plugin_debugger.dll Another idea, please?

Comment: Check the logs and see if it actually gets loaded or if there's an error loading it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that PL/PgSQL debugger extension is installed in a schema different of public, after setting search_path in postgresql.conf to the right schema debugger is ok.